# How to retrieve the contents of file and store it in binary format in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, database

I am making a file uploader using html tags. My table consists of id(Primary Key), Name varchar(50), ContentType(which shows me the extension of the file) and Data varbinary(Max) which will store the contents of the file. Below is my html:

```
     <tr>
     <td class="label" style="width:15%">
     Upload File
     </td>
     <td class="description" >
     <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" class="largeTextField" multiple="multiple"   
     style="width:260px;"/>
     <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload"  onclick="UploadFile()" />
     </td>
     <div class="validator" id="txtUploadFileVld" style="display: none">
     *</div>
     </tr>
```

and javascript function UploadFile():

```
    function UploadFile() {

    var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
    var filePath = $('#FileUpload1').val();
    var contenttype = $("#FileUpload1").val().split('.').pop();
    var AJAX = new AJAXsupport();
    AJAX.resetVar();
    AJAX.addData('id', id);
    AJAX.addData('Name', $('#FileUpload1').val().split('\\').pop());
    AJAX.addData('ContentType', $('#FileUpload1').val().split('.').pop());

    AJAX.addData('CLDone', 'UploadFile');
    var sucSave = function () {
        alert(AJAX.getMessage())



        }
    customSave(AJAX, sucSave);
     }
```

My filename and content type is correctly being saved in the database. But I dont know how to retrieve the contents of the file and save it in my database. The file will be saved in binary format since I have datatype varbinary in my table. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try the efollowing code:

```
    string strQuery = "select Name, ContentType, Data from tblFiles where id=@id";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    if (dt != null)
    {
        download(dt);
    }

    private void download (DataTable dt)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="

        + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
}

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sda.Dispose()
        con.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have added the GetData() method.